# Personalize sensor's output and save it to file

Tags: sensors

I was wondering how to reformat terminal output for logging information. More specifically I would like to reformat the output of the  `sensors` command from the `lm-sensors` package and write it to a file. The output looks something like this:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +61.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +99.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +63.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +62.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +59.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +63.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +61.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +61.5°C
```

My purpose for reformatting is, for later using the data with gnuplot (realtime plotting). So the result should look similar to this:

```
# Timestamp [hh:mm:ss]    temp1 [°C]       temp2 [°C]     ... 
13:45:52                  65.0             29.0            .
13:45:53                  66.0             28.0            .
13:45:54                  64.0             27.0            .
13:45:55                  55.0             26.0            .
...                       ...              ...             .
```

I would like to use this on multiple computers with a different amount of sensors this would require some sort of loop. But from where to where would one loop and how to eliminate the redundant lines (e.g. acpitz-virtual-0, Adapter: Virtual device, ...). Also i'm aware of the `lm-sensors` package capabilities to produce graphs. But I would like to realize a homebrew solution and also keep the question more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem and implemented a solution:

Using `sed` to parse the piped output of `sensors` with regular expressions the result is appended to the log file.

1. The date is written as UNIX timestamp to file and formated to stdout. To suppress the line break the `echo -n "$(date +"%H:%M:%S")` command is used.
2. Next the output of `sensors` is piped into `sed` to parse every line to find the temperatures by searching for `°C`.
3. The result is agine piped to `sed`. Now the string is devided into three parts: The name of the sensor at the beginning with colon and whitespaces `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*:\s*`, The temperature consisting of sign, numbers and point `\([0-9.+-]*\)` and the rest to the end of the string `.*$`. The second part is marked as reference by the use of the brackets.
4. The result is again piped to `sed` to remove the line breaks. [Click for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)
5. The scripts sleeps for X seconds. (In my case 5 seconds.)

The resulting batch script:

```
# Printing the names of the columns as first row in file
echo "Time;     temp1;  temp2;  Physical id 0;  Core 0; Core 1; Core 2; Core 3; SIO Temp;       temp3" > Temperatures.log
while true
do
    # Printing the time and all temperatures to stdout
    echo -n "$(date +"%H:%M:%S"): "
    sensors | sed -n "/Â°C/p" | sed "s/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*:\s*\([0-9.+-]*\).*$/\1/" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/;\t/g'

    # Logging time as UNIX time and temperatures to file
    echo -n "$(date +"%s");     " >> Temperatures.log
    sensors | sed -n "/Â°C/p" | sed "s/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*:\s*\([0-9.+-]*\).*$/\1/" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/;\t/g' >> Temperatures.log

    # Sleeping for X seconds
    sleep 5
done
```